# How to generate constructor that calls superclass constructor using JavaPoet

Tags: java, annotation-processing, javapoet, annotation-processor

I want to generate a class that extends other class using JavaPoet.

For example I have this class:

```
@MyAnnotation
public class ClassA {
  public ClassA(String paramA, int paramB) {
     // some code
  }
}
```

and I want to generate new class like this one:

```
public class Generated_ClassA extends ClassA {
  public Generated_ClassA (String paramA, int paramB) {
     super(paramA, paramB);
  }
}
```

However, I don't see any ready-to-use API in JavaPoet to create constructors which are calling superclass constructors. How it is possible to do this and what are the best practices?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by using [`MethodSpec.Builder#addStatement`](https://square.github.io/javapoet/javadoc/javapoet/com/squareup/javapoet/MethodSpec.Builder.html#addStatement(java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.Object...))

```
MethodSpec.constructorBuilder()
          .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
          .addParameter(String.class, "paramA")
          .addParameter(Integer.TYPE, "paramB")
          .addStatement("super(paramA, paramB)")
          .build();
```

You can also also use [`MethodSpec.Builder#addCode`](https://square.github.io/javapoet/javadoc/javapoet/com/squareup/javapoet/MethodSpec.Builder.html#addCode(com.squareup.javapoet.CodeBlock)) and build same code using [`CodeBlock.Builder#addStatement`](https://square.github.io/javapoet/javadoc/javapoet/com/squareup/javapoet/CodeBlock.Builder.html#addStatement(java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.Object...)) but unfortunately *AFAIK* there is no specific builders available for calling `super`.